# Running event by clicking button c++

Tags: c++, winapi, events, button, click

I'm trying to run simple event by clicking button, but my code doesn't seems to work. There are two issues. First, I need to run `int nmr()` when I click on button. Second, I need to insert file path I chosen by OpenFileDialog in `string inFile()`. This is my code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND hWndButton

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateMenubar(hWnd);

        hWndButton = CreateWindow("button", "Go!",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,15,45,60,25,hWnd,
            (HMENU) ID_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);

        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDM_FILE_OPEN:
            openFileDialog1;
            if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog())
            {
                MessageBox(0, openFileDialog1->FileName, _T("File name"),
                    MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            }
            openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 1;
            openFileDialog1->Flags |= OFN_SHOWHELP;
            openFileDialog1->InitialDir = _T("C:\\Windows\\");
            openFileDialog1->Title = _T("Open Text File");

            break;

        case ID_BUTTON:

            int nmr();

            break;

        case IDM_FILE_QUIT:
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            break;
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
        break;
        }

return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

void CreateMenubar(HWND hwnd)
{
HMENU hMenubar;
HMENU hMenu;

hMenubar = CreateMenu();
hMenu = CreateMenu();

AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_OPEN, L"&Open");
AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_FILE_QUIT, L"&Quit");

AppendMenuW(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hMenu, L"&File");
    SetMenu(hwnd, hMenubar);
}



OpenFileDialog::OpenFileDialog(void)
    {
        this->DefaultExtension = 0;
        this->FileName = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH];
        this->Filter = 0;
        this->FilterIndex = 0;
        this->Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
        this->InitialDir = 0;
        this->Owner = 0;
        this->Title = 0;
    }

    bool OpenFileDialog::ShowDialog()
    {
        OPENFILENAME ofn;

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = this->Owner;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = this->DefaultExtension;
    ofn.lpstrFile = this->FileName;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = this->Filter;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = this->FilterIndex;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = this->InitialDir;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = this->Title;
    ofn.Flags = this->Flags;

    GetOpenFileName(&ofn);

    if (_tcslen(this->FileName) == 0) return false;


    return true;
}


int nmr()
{
    string inFile(openFileDialog1->FileName);
    string outFile("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\outT1.txt");

    int numline = 0;
    double v1;
    string s;
    string v2, v3, v4;
    string line_keep, line_avoid;
    ifstream in_stream;
    ofstream out_stream;
    in_stream.open(inFile.c_str());
    out_stream.open(outFile.c_str());
    if (in_stream.fail() || out_stream.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error ocured during oppening file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code is horribly formated. Also `int nmr();` has to be just `nmr();`

Comment: Your edit completely changed the question. I rolled it back.

Comment: @Vinzenz I think something is eating his leftmost four spaces within function bodies; at least that's what it looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int nmr();
```

This **declares** a function named `nmr`. That's not what you want. You want to **call** the function of the same name that you defined elsewhere. You mean to write, simply:

```
int retval = nmr();
```

That calls the function.

If you don't care about the return value you can simply do:

```
nmr();
```

You will need to define the function `nmr` above the call, or use a forward declaration.

It would make much more sense to pass the file name to `nmr()` as a parameter.

```
int nmr(const string& inFileName)
```

Using an `int` return value to indicate success is far from idiomatic in C++. If you must use the return value to indicate success, then a `bool` would be more appropriate. Older variants of C had no boolean type, which is perhaps where you learnt the concept of returning an `int` to indicate success. But it's time to unlearn that concept when writing new code. You still need to understand it when interfacing with existing code.

Comment: I've made a forward declaration `int nmr(const string& inFileName)` , edited `LRESULT` and `int nmr(const string& inFileName)`. It still doesn't work. I simply need to choose file and edit it by ckicking button, using `int nmr()` function.

Comment: I think I answered the question that you asked. I can't debug your new code that I cannot see.